# Cannot Change the Icon of a sub form at runtime

Tags: delphi

I have a Search and Replace dialog in my application, and I want to change the form's Icon according to the mode of the form, i.e. search or replace.

This is the routine I am using  to configure the form:

```
procedure TfmFindReplace.SetFormMode(Mode: tConfigMode);
begin
  // Set up form for Search or Replace.
  if Mode = fcmCurrent then exit;
  fFormMode := Mode;
  pnlReplaceHldr.Visible := FormMode=fcmReplace;
  chkPromptOnReplace.Visible := FormMode=fcmReplace;
  rbCurrentProject.Visible := (fmProjManagerVT.IsOpen) and Not (Mode=fcmReplace);
  if mode=fcmFind then begin
    Caption := 'Find Text';
    Icon.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'SEARCH');
    image1.Picture.Icon.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'SEARCH')
  end
  else begin
    Caption := 'Replace Text';
    Icon.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'REPLACE');
    image1.Picture.Icon.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'REPLACE')
  end;
end;
```

I cannot get the Icon on the title bar to change.  Just to check that I was picking up the Icon from the resource file, I added an image to the form to check if it was being reloaded.

I am using Delphi 11.1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Theme I am using is overriding the setting.  (Im using the Windows11 Dark and Light Themes)
My work around which makes the transition between form types rather clunky is this:

```
  StyleElements := [seFont,seClient];
  if mode=fcmFind then begin
    Caption := 'Find Text';
    Icon.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'SEARCH');
  end
  else begin
    Caption := 'Replace Text';
    Icon.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'REPLACE');
  end;
  StyleElements := [seFont,seClient,seBorder];
```

On Setting the style elements it appears the form gets cleared then repainted.
Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: Try SetWindowPos(Handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_NOZORDER or
        SWP_DRAWFRAME or SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE);

Comment: @dwrbudr Currently I hide the window before the above code and show it after the routine.  This makes the transition cleaner but not seamless. I tried your suggestion but it looks no better than the hide/show approach.  If I leave the Icon unchanged the form  simply shows/hides components on the form without appearing to repaint the whole form.